# How can I use a combination of the min and find functions in Matlab to find how many zeroes are in the vector?

Tags: matlab

Title says it all. I Know what both of these functions do individually, but combining them is proving difficult.

Comment: `numel(find(a == min(abs(a))))`

Comment: @Divakar even simpler ;) `numel(find(a==min(0)))`

Comment: `sum(a==0)`. no `min` and no `find` necessary.

Comment: What about `numel(a) - nnz(a)`?  `nnz` finds the total number of non-zero entries, so if you want to find the number of zero entries, we know that `nz + nnz = numel(a)` where `nz` is the number of zeroes, so `nz = numel(a) - nnz(a);`.

Comment: Why don't you post answers guys ?

Answer (score 1):

Collecting all of the answers from the comments, you can do it in a variety of ways:

1. `numel(find(a == min(0)))` (à la Try Hard).  The `min(0)` is rather superfluous as you can simply do `a == 0`, but because you are required to use `min`, we need that there.  The general case is (à la Divakar) `numel(find(a == min(abs(a))));`.  This is assuming that the minimum of `a` is zero.  Essentially, this finds all locations that are zero, and determining how many of these elements are zero is done with `numel`.
2. I personally would not use `find` and `min`.  A.Donda suggests to use `sum`, which is certainly more elegant... so do: `sum(a == 0)`.  `a == 0` produces a logical vector where `1` at a position means that the corresponding element at this position in `a` is 0 and `0` otherwise.  We sum up all of the cases where we have `1`, which produces how many zero values there are.
3. This was one I came up with:  `numel(a) - nnz(a)`.  This comes from the fact that we can decompose the total number of elements in a vector to be the number of **zero** elements, added with the total of **non-zero** elements, or `nz(a) + nnz(a) = numel(a)`, and so `nz(a) = numel(a) - nnz(a)`.  There is a function in MATLAB called `nnz`, which counts how many non-zero elements there are in a vector or matrix.  Therefore, you can count how many zero elements there are by `numel(a) - nnz(a)`.  It's not as elegant as `sum(a == 0)`, but it's certainly another way to achieve what you want.